# Are foreach's in alternative syntax implemented as stack?

Tags: php, foreach

I am having a problem with putting a foreach inside a foreach in HTML/PHP. I am wondering if the foreach's in the alternative structure are implemented as a stack?

My code can be found below.

I have this array that contains data:

```
 $tasks = [
    [
        "category" => "to do",
        "items" => [
            [
                "title" => "Buy fireworks for New Year",
                "description" => "Make sure they are not dangerous.",
                "id" => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

And here is my HTML in which I am trying to:

1. Display the category name.
2. Loop through the tasks in the $task variable to put the items inside a `<li>` inside a `<ul>`.

   `<div class="task-container">
       <h2 class="task-container__title"><?=$taskGroup['category']?></h2>
       <? if (count($taskGroup['items'])) : ?>
           <ul class="task-container__items">
               <?php foreach ($taskGroup['items'] as $ta) : ?>
                   <li class="task-container__item">
                   <div class="task-container__card">
                       <p class="task-container__card-title">
                           <?=$ta['title']?>
                       </p>
                       <div class="task-container__card-promote"></div>
                   </div>
               </li>
               <? endforeach; ?>
           </ul>
       <? endif; ?>
   </div>`

As you can see, I am looping through the categories in the $tasks variable. Then for each $items in the category, I want to loop through them and add them as `<li>` elements. However, I always get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...
```

when I add the second foreach inside the first foreach.

Am I doing something wrong? Or nesting a foreach inside a foreach is forbidden in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try never to use `<?` to start a PHP script, use `<?php` instead. As "spaghetti code" as it may be, it's PHP so deal with it hahaha... Also, you should have clarified that `$taskGroup` is basically `$tasks[0]` in this example

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
 $tasks = [
    [
        "category" => "to do",
        "items" => [
            [
                "title" => "Buy fireworks for New Year",
                "description" => "Make sure they are not dangerous.",
                "id" => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
$taskGroup = $tasks[0]

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="task-container">
        <h2 class="task-container__title"><?= $taskGroup['category'] ?></h2>
        <?php if (count($taskGroup['items'])): ?>
            <ul class="task-container__items">
                <?php foreach ($taskGroup['items'] as $ta): ?>
                    <li class="task-container__item">
                    <div class="task-container__card">
                        <p class="task-container__card-title">
                            <?=$ta['title']?>
                        </p>
                        <div class="task-container__card-promote"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```